# `window` is not being exposed to Jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I have a test that imports a component that in turn imports a helper file that uses the `window` object to pull out a query string parameter. I get the following error about `window`:

```
FAIL  src/js/components/__tests__/Controls.test.jsx
 ● Test suite failed to run

   ReferenceError: window is not defined
```

*Controls.jsx*:

```
import { Unwrapped as Controls } from '../Controls'

describe('<MyInterestsControls />', () => {
  it('should render the component with the fixture data', () => {
    const component = shallow(
      <UnwrappedMyInterestControls
        dashboardData={dashboardData}
        loadingFlags={{ controls: false }}
      />
    )
    expect(component).toMatchSnapshot()
  })
})
```

*Controls.jsx* imports *./helpers/services.js* which contains the following:

```
import * as queryString from 'query-string'
const flag = queryString.parse(window.location.search).flag || 'off'
                               ^^^^^^ this seems to be the problem
```

I have attempted to import jsdom:

```
import { JSDOM } from 'jsdom'
```

And implemented the solution presented [here](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/guides/jsdom.md#using-enzyme-with-jsdom) at the top of my test file:

```
const { JSDOM } = require('jsdom');

const jsdom = new JSDOM('<!doctype html><html><body></body></html>');
const { window } = jsdom;

function copyProps(src, target) {
  const props = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(src)
    .filter(prop => typeof target[prop] === 'undefined')
    .map(prop => Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(src, prop));
  Object.defineProperties(target, props);
}

global.window = window;
global.document = window.document;
global.navigator = {
  userAgent: 'node.js',
};
copyProps(window, global);
```

However, I still get the error and it seems JSDOM's *window* object isn't exposed to the test.

#### How can I properly expose global objects like `window` or `document` to a Jest test?

###### Relevant *package.json*

```
  "scripts": {
    "test:watch": "NODE_ENV=test jest --watch"
  },
  ...
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
    "jest": "^20.0.4",
    "jest-mock": "^21.2.0",
    "jsdom": "^11.0.0",
    ...
  },
  ...
  "jest": {
    "verbose": true,
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/js/helpers/preparePayload.js",
      "src/js/components-ni",
      "!**/node_modules/**",
      "!**/dist/**"
    ],
    "coverageThreshold": {
      "global": {
        "statements": 50,
        "branches": 50,
        "functions": 50,
        "lines": 75
      }
    },
    "testEnvironment": "jest-environment-node"
  }
```

Comment: ^^ Since I really messed up the markdown _and_ the link in the bounty description, this is the link to [the enzyme docs](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/guides/jsdom.html)

Comment: which version of jest are you using?

Comment: @JoseAPL jest@^20.0.4, react@16.0.0

Comment: could you please add your `package.json`, by default jest uses the `testEnvironment` to browser-like `jsdom` so you don't have to import `jsdom` to your unit tests

Comment: @JoseAPL I've added the relevant portions from the package.json

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jest test fails with "window is not defined"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46274889/jest-test-fails-with-window-is-not-defined)

Answer (score 25):

As mentioned by @RiZKiT in the comment below, since Jest v27.0 [the default test environment has changed](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#testenvironment-string) from `"jsdom"` to `"node"`.

Your problem relies on the configuration.

In the moment you set:

```
"testEnvironment": "jest-environment-node"
```

You are changing the default configuration from Jest which is browser-like to `jest-environment-node` *(Node.js-like)* meaning that your test will be run under a [Node.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js) environment

**To solve it either you set your `testEnvironment` to `jsdom`
Or you remove the `testEnvironment` from your configuration, so it will take the default value in your`package.json`:**

```
 ...
  "jest": {
    "verbose": true,
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/js/helpers/preparePayload.js",
      "src/js/components-ni",
      "!**/node_modules/**",
      "!**/dist/**"
    ],
    "coverageThreshold": {
      "global": {
        "statements": 50,
        "branches": 50,
        "functions": 50,
        "lines": 75
      }
    }
  }
```

### This is what they say in the documentation

> `testEnvironment` [string] # Default: "jsdom"
>
> The test environment that
> will be used for testing. The default environment in Jest is a
> browser-like environment through jsdom. If you are building a node
> service, you can use the node option to use a node-like environment
> instead.

---

## Do you need the `node` environment?

As I could see, your tests are meant to be run under a browser-like environment.

If you ever need an explicit Node.js environment, better you isolate that case using `@jest-environment`:

```
/**
 * @jest-environment node
 */

test('use node in this test file', () => {
  expect(true).not.toBeNull();
});
```

Or the other way around, if you are meant to run the tests under a Node.js environment:

```
/**
 * @jest-environment jsdom
 */

test('use jsdom in this test file', () => {
  const element = document.createElement('div');
  expect(element).not.toBeNull();
});
```

---

## Conclusion

With this you can avoid importing `jsdom` manually and setting global variables. `jsdom` will mock the [DOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) implementation automatically.

If you need to change the environment for your tests, use the notation `@jest-environment`.

Comment: Since Jest 27 "jsdom" isn't the default anymore but "node", see https://github.com/facebook/jest/pull/9874 and here https://jestjs.io/blog/2021/05/25/jest-27#flipping-defaults.So you have to set "jsdom" explicitly now.

Answer (score 4):

You could try doing

```
global.window = new jsdom.JSDOM().window;
global.document = window.document;
```

Comment: Why would that help? Can you [elaborate](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46105819/edit) in your answer? (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question/answer should appear as if it was written today.)

Answer (score 4):

See *[Expose jsdom to global environment #2460](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2460#issuecomment-324630534)*

It seems like one of the contributors declared that he is not planning to expose jsdom to global under the Jest environment.

However, you could use `Object.defineProperty(window, 'location', {value: '…'}` API to approach it, [like the developer from Facebook do](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2460#issuecomment-209698782). In your case it could be like:

```
    Object.defineProperty(window, 'location', {
      value: {
        search: ...
      },
    })
```

Comment: Can you provide an example showing how to use this in a test. As is, I still get the reference error.

Comment: This solved my issue, just need to add it in `beforeEach()` of the test

Answer (score 4):

Here you can find examples of how to do this:

*[DOM Testing React Applications with Jest](https://www.codementor.io/pkodmad/dom-testing-react-application-jest-k4ll4f8sd)*

For example:

```
import {jsdom} from 'jsdom';

const documentHTML = '<!doctype html><html><body><div id="root"></div></body></html>';
global.document = jsdom(documentHTML);
global.window = document.parentWindow;
```

Comment: `import { jsdom } from 'jsdom'; const documentHTML =
  '<!doctype html><html><body><div id="root"></div></body></html>';
global.document = jsdom(documentHTML);
global.window = document.parentWindow;
import { Unwrapped as UnwrappedMyComponent } from '../MyComponent';` (MyComponent uses `window`) => `ReferenceError: window is not defined`

Answer (score 2):

You can simply mock `location`:

```
global.location = {search: 'someSearchString'}
```

Also note, that `global` in your test is the global context for the file to test (`global === window`)

Note this will only work if your module make the `window.location` call after the test has been finishing import all the modules.

```
export default () => window.location
```

So if your module looks like this:

```
const  l = window.location
export default l
```

it will not work. In this case you could mock the module using `jest.mock`.

Comment: When I add this object to the top of my test: `global.window = {
  location: {
    search: {
      api: 'fixture'
    }
  }
}` I still receive `ReferenceError: window is not defined` when I `import { Unwrapped as UnwrappedMyComponent } from '../MyComponent'` which contains itself contains an `import` of another script which uses `window.location.search`. I've tried it at the top of the file and also below my enzyme named imports. Have I done something incorrectly?

Comment: No, if the imported modules use `window` in its initialization code then there  is no way to set this. In this case I would mock out this dependency.

Comment: How do you mean? Can you give an example?

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: _Note this will only work if your module make the window.location call after the test has been finishing import all the modules._ > I'm not sure I understand what you mean by this or how I can control it. _In this case you could mock the module using jest.mock_ Are you talking about [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-mock)?

Comment: Hmm. I've been playing with that. Can provide a working example for implementation there?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, but I think you could do it with `jest.fn()`:

```
global.window = jest.fn(() => {
  location: { ... }
})
```

Maybe even as `window = jest.fn(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was injecting a custom environment file's value into a [Vue.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vue.js) component using [Ruby on Rails](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_on_Rails). So, I was getting a base URL for assets as undefined in a Jest snapshot. The solution was to include a setup file in **jest.config.js** → **setupFiles** as an array like below.

**jest.config.js**

```
{
  setupFiles: [
    "./app/javascript/tests/testsConfig.js",
  ],
}
```

**testsConfig.js**

```
process.env.BASE_DOMAIN = process.env.BASE_DOMAIN || 'http://localhost:3000/'

window.TestsConfig = {
  "CLOUD_FRONT_BASE_URL": "https://cdn.site.com"
}
```