# Jest test fails with "window is not defined"

Tags: webpack, jestjs, yarnpkg

I am trying to get started with state-of-the-art web development learning [React](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/React_(JavaScript_library)) and [Redux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redux_(JavaScript_library)).

Right now I am stuck at getting tests running. For some reason, Jest fails with

```
Task :frontend:test
yarn jest v1.0.2
$ "/Users/gunnar/git/app.oakstair.se/frontend/node_modules/.bin/jest"
FAIL src/containers/App/App.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

 ReferenceError: window is not defined

  at Object.<anonymous> (config/polyfills.js:18:1)
  at next (native)
  at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)
```

I have googled for a while without any success...

[image: This is my starting test.js]

[image: And this my App test code]

Comment: could you please add your test code ?

Comment: I added two images.I could make the repo public but its quite big since it is based on a react/redux template that I bought which contains a lot!

Comment: Do you run it with jsdom?

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and take the appropriate [action](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46274889/edit). Thanks in advance.

Comment: Somewhat related: *[How can I mock the JavaScript 'window' object using Jest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41885841/)*. A crypto answer states *"Instead of `window`, use `global`"*.

Answer (score 103):

I had the same issue and I do not believe modifying globals is the way to do it.

The issue was because in my Jest configuration I had `testEnvironment` set to `node` when it should've been `jsdom`. For me, this setting was located in file *package.json* as defined by the React starter app.

Comment: For info `jsdom` is the default value (see https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html#testenvironment-string) so unless you have overwritten it (like they do in `create-react-app`) you should be ok

Comment: If you need to support canvas you'll need to set `testEnvironment` to `environment-jsdom-fourteen` and install it with `npm install --save-dev jest-environment-jsdom-fourteen`  https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom#canvas-support

Comment: If you use react-native, chances are you're using the `preset: react-native` jest config which overwrites the default value to exclude the DOM: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/tutorial-react-native#environment

Comment: i am also getting same error but i am using vue.js , if any suggestions please help me

Comment: testEnvironment:jsdom' doesn't pass value of  window.location.href from one function to another, but setting globals: {
    window: {
     location works ok https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46274889/jest-test-fails-with-window-is-not-defined/72275917#72275917

Answer (score 85):

In your *package.json* file, add `window` like a **global**. Something like this:

```js
"jest": {
  "verbose": true,
  "preset": "react-native",
  "setupFiles": ["./jest/setup.js"],
  "testRegex": "(/tests/.*|\\.(test|spec))\\.(ts|tsx|js)$",
  "transformIgnorePatterns": [
    "node_modules/(?!(jest-)?react-native|lottie-react-native)"
  ],
  "globals": {
    "window": {}
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately create-react-app does not support configuring globals this way. Any suggestion there?

Comment: @Faust See JacksonHaenchen's answer

Comment: This is could be helpful, but it's an empty object anyway, so you have no properties such as `userAgent`, etc. Maybe it's a way to map here an object from jsdom or something. Would be way more helpful

Comment: Consider to populate properties like window.location -see Solders's answer below https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46274889/jest-test-fails-with-window-is-not-defined/72275917#72275917

Answer (score 43):

### 2021 (Jest 27)

Jest's `testEnvironment` default used to be `jsdom`. It was changed to `node` starting with version 27.

You can set `testEnvironment: 'jsdom'` in your configuration file to keep using JSDOM.

However, `'node'` seems to be a lot faster, so you should be mocking browser APIs where possible.

*[Jest 27: New Defaults for Jest, 2021 edition](https://jestjs.io/blog/2021/05/25/jest-27)*

Comment: But it sounds that it should be possible to have "window" and etc in "node" env. Is it? I'd like to speed up my project with switching from jsdom to node, but wonder if it possible, cause I have same issues with undefined "window".

Comment: also need to install jest-environment-jsdom npm module seperately

Comment: Can you address the need for 'jest-environment-jsdom' in your answer (even if it is not required)? And possible ***silent failure*** if it isn't installed(?). (But ************* ***without*** *************** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today)

Comment: @Vipul Dessai: As of version 28 (released 2022-04-25): *"As of Jest 28 "jest-environment-jsdom" is no longer shipped by default. Make sure to install it separately."*. From [its blog post](https://jestjs.io/blog/2022/04/25/jest-28): *"Please note that both of the removed modules (jest-environment-jsdom and jest-jasmine2) are still actively maintained and tested in the same way, so the only breaking change here is that you'll need to explicitly install them."*

Answer (score 7):

```
npm i jest-environment-jsdom
```

#### File *index.test.tsx*

```
/**
 * @jest-environment jsdom
 */
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., why do you need to install something extra? Is that really necessary? What is the advantage? What is the idea/gist? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68911353/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: It seems to be a requirement for Jest version 28 (released 2022-04-25): *"As of Jest 28 "jest-environment-jsdom" is no longer shipped by default. Make sure to install it separately."*. From [its blog post](https://jestjs.io/blog/2022/04/25/jest-28): *"Please note that both of the removed modules (jest-environment-jsdom and jest-jasmine2) are still actively maintained and tested in the same way, so the only breaking change here is that you'll need to explicitly install them."*

Comment: Can you make your answer more comprehensive, please? (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today.)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72013449/upgrading-jest-to-v29-error-test-environment-jest-environment-jsdom-cannot-be

Answer (score 7):

If you want to keep `testEnvironment` set to `node`, you can configure a global `window` in your jest.config.js/ts and then mock what you need in your test cases.

It works fine as long as you don't need any advanced features. It is the same answer as some of the high rated previous ones, but including some examples.

```
import type {Config} from '@jest/types';

const config: Config.InitialOptions = {
  ...jestConfig,
  testEnvironment: "node",
  globals: {
    window: {
     location: {}
    }
  }
};

export default config;
```

**SomeTestCase.spec.ts**

```
test('Is correct href', () => {
  window.location.href = 'https://somedomain.com';
  expect(window.location.href).toBe('https://somedomain.com');
})
```