# when i am trying to run test cases it shows me shallowMount error,How to fix ShallowMount error in VUE.JS?

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, vue-test-utils

i am wrighting test cases for LoginNew.vue component , when i am trying to import that component inside the spec.js file i am getting shallowMount error [[check my error here]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgAS4.png) ,i don't know why i am getting this error please help me to fix this issue
`jest.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
    moduleNameMapper:{
    "~(.*)$": "<rootDir>/resources/js/$1",
    },
    setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>resources/src/tests/setup.js'],
    resolver: require.resolve(`jest-pnp-resolver`),
    testEnvironment: `node`,
};
```

`LoginNew.vue`

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1 id="title">Login</h1>
        <input type="text" id="input-username"/>
        <input type="password" id="input-password"/>
        <button id="btn-sign-in">Sign In</button>

        </div>
</template>
<script>

    export default {
        name: 'LoginNew'
    }
</script>
```

`Login.spec.js`

```
import  LoginNew from '../../src/Pages/LoginNew.vue';
import{shallowMount} from '@vue/test-utils';
describe('LoginNew.vue',()=>{
    describe('When Loaded',()=>{
        it('has the required elements',()=>{
            const wrapper =shallowMount(LoginNew);
            expect(wrapper.find('#input-username').exists()).toBe(false);
            expect(wrapper.find('#input-password').exists()).toBe(false);
        });
    });
});
```

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "vue-fundoo",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve --port 3000",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@vue/composition-api": "^1.0.0-rc.9",
    "@vuelidate/core": "^2.0.0-alpha.18",
    "@vuelidate/validators": "^2.0.0-alpha.15",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "bootstrap": "^5.0.1",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-axios": "^3.2.4",
    "vue-router": "^3.5.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.12",
    "vuelidate": "^0.7.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^1.2.0",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "babel-jest": "^27.0.2",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
    "jest": "^27.0.3",
    "node-sass": "^5.0.0",
    "sass": "^1.19.0",
    "sass-loader": "^10.1.1",
    "vue-jest": "^3.0.7",
    "vue-test-utils": "^1.0.0-beta.11",
    "webpack": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    },
    "rules": {}
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead"
  ],
  "jest": {
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.vue$": "vue-jest",
      "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the content of your `jest.config.js` file? Do you have one in the project ?

Comment: Hello @MichalLevý, i added my jest.config.js in my code please check it once

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jest test fails with window is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46274889/jest-test-fails-with-window-is-not-defined)

Comment: @MichalLevý, not this solution, i am getting shallowMount error

Comment: Doesn't matter, error message is the same. Problem is in the `testEnvironment: 'node'`

Comment: Above mentioned solution is going to work in my case na..?

Comment: Hello @MichalLevý,I changed according what you suggested it's not working in my case getting same error

Comment: Can you share some info from package.json?
What versions are used of Jest, @vue/test-utils, vue-jest?

Comment: @kunukn,I updated my package.json in question section please check

Comment: "jest": "^27.0.3",    "vue-test-utils": "^1.0.0-beta.11","vue-jest": "^3.0.7", These are the versions I am using @Kunukn

Comment: vue-test-utils should be deleted. It is deprecated in favor of @vue/test-utils which is already in package.json https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-test-utils.

Comment: Can you move the "jest" with transform info in package.json into the jest.config.js?
And update the tests to be truthy, e.g. `expect(wrapper.find('#input-username').exists()).toBe(true);`

Comment: @Kunukn,yeah i changed but getting  some error means it's expect a regex things   ,This is the error i am getting                            SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

    > 1 | import  LoginNew from '../../src/Pages/LoginNew.vue';
        | ^
      2 | import{shallowMount} from '@vue/test-utils';
      3 | describe('LoginNew.vue',()=>{
      4 |     describe('When Loaded',()=>{

      at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1479:14)
      at Object.<anonymous> (tests/unit/Login.spec.js:1:1)

Answer (score 0):

Update the jest configuration to

`testEnvironment: 'jsdom'`

The defaults has been changed for Jest 27
Read more about it here.

https://jestjs.io/blog/2021/05/25/jest-27

Comment: Hello @Kunukn, i changed to jsdom but sill getting same error