# JavaScript - can't get jsdom document in Jest test

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, dom, jestjs, jsdom

I have a module that provides some convenience functions for DOM manipulation that I'm trying to test with Jest and jsdom, but I seem to be doing something wrong in instantiating it.

From reading other questions and answers (such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46785146/3358139)) I understand that Jest's testing environment is automatically set to use jsdom and that you need to replace `global.document`, but it's not working as I currently have it.

Here's the smallest test case to reproduce the problem:

```js
// domUtils.js

function el(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
}
```

and

```
// domUtils.test.js

import { JSDOM } from "jsdom";

import * as domUtils from "../src/domUtils";

describe("DOM operations", () => {
    // Workaround for jsdom issue 2304 - needed for later localStorage tests
    const url = "http://localhost";

    const documentHTML = '<!DOCTYPE html><div id="lorem" class="test">Lorem ipsum</div>';

    global.document = new JSDOM(documentHTML, { url });

    test("Get an element from the DOM", () => {
        const loremDiv = domUtils.el("lorem");

        expect(loremDiv.constructor.name).toEqual("HTMLDivElement");
    });
}
```

This results in `TypeError: Cannot read property 'constructor' of null`. Replacing the call to `domUtils.el()` with `document.getElementById()` results in the same error.

Is it a loading order problem of some sort, or something else?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

OK, the solution was - I totally didn't need to do any of the jsdom setup myself because Jest has already done it. You can set `document.body.innerHTML` directly in your tests and Bob's your uncle.

I had gotten to Jest's [very brief page on DOM testing](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/tutorial-jquery) and skipped over the code example that uses jQuery, because I'm not using jQuery - and got to the paragraph that mentions it provides jsdom. But it didn't explain that, or link to the jsdom docs, so I searched and found them. And they don't mention Jest even once - so I followed the instructions on how to set up jsdom, which turned out to be completely redundant and lead to the error I was getting. Honestly, the one sentence "If you're using Jest, you don't need to instantiate jsdom yourself" would have saved me about two days of pulling my hair out.